# Tree Graph Collection Querying in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm building an app where I'm evaluating which way to go or what to use using NodeJS... I want to build a tree graph structure like this

`parent -> 2 children -> each child also with 2 children -> repeat...`

And I want to be able to fetch all the members from say `a particular parent to its relative 4th generation`. Is this possible and could an example be provided before I dive into GraphQL?